# Split Audio but with silence detection after minutes

Tags: python, audio

they are many threads about splitting audios using silence detection
im trying for hours to get a method working which split audios in 1 minute clips but with silence detection at the end, for example split at one minute but if there is no silence so go more until you find the first silence spot....
Is there a way to do this?

```
# Import the AudioSegment class for processing audio and the
# split_on_silence function for separating out silent chunks.
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence

# Define a function to normalize a chunk to a target amplitude.
def match_target_amplitude(aChunk, target_dBFS):
    ''' Normalize given audio chunk '''
    change_in_dBFS = target_dBFS - aChunk.dBFS
    return aChunk.apply_gain(change_in_dBFS)

# Load your audio.
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(r"C:\Users\Snur\Pycharm Projects\Gitlab\v\ubuntu.wav")

# Split track where the silence is 2 seconds or more and get chunks using
# the imported function.
chunks = split_on_silence (
    # Use the loaded audio.
    song,
    # Specify that a silent chunk must be at least 2 seconds or 2000 ms long.
    min_silence_len = 1000,
    # Consider a chunk silent if it's quieter than -16 dBFS.
    # (You may want to adjust this parameter.)
    silence_thresh = -16
)
# Process each chunk with your parameters
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    # Create a silence chunk that's 0.5 seconds (or 500 ms) long for padding.
    silence_chunk = AudioSegment.silent(duration=500)

    # Add the padding chunk to beginning and end of the entire chunk.
    audio_chunk = silence_chunk + chunk + silence_chunk

    # Normalize the entire chunk.
    normalized_chunk = match_target_amplitude(audio_chunk, -20.0)

    # Export the audio chunk with new bitrate.
    print("Exporting chunk{0}.wav.".format(i))
    normalized_chunk.export(
        "chunk{0}.wav".format(i),
        bitrate = "192k",
        format = "wav"
    )
```

Comment: you should describe what is going wrong with your sample code - are you getting an error? which one? or is just not behaving as expected? What are your expectations and what are your results?

Comment: it splits correctly but I want that he splits it into one minute parts

Comment: what have you tried to achieve that and why is/isn't working?